# Kmeans centroids not in center of cluster

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, clustering, k-means

i've been trying to implement Kmeans algorithm from scratch and the problem with my centroids is they don't seem to be going towards the center of clusters.

[image]

here is the code i wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, k=3, max_iter=50):
        self.k = k
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.centroids = None
        self.data=None
    def preprocess(self):
        self.data = self.data.dropna()

    def load_data(self, data):
        cols = ["overall", "age", "potential", "wage_eur", "value_eur"]
        data = data[cols]
        data = data[:2500]
        scaler = StandardScaler().set_output(transform="pandas")
        data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
        self.data = data
        print(self.data.describe())
        self.centroids = self.data.sample(n=self.k)
        self.centroids.index = [i for i in range(self.k)]
    def __calculate_distance(self, distance):
        for i in self.data.index:
                for j in range(self.k):
                    distance.loc[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(((self.data.loc[i, :] - self.centroids.loc[j, :])**2)))
        return distance
    def __plot(self, data, labels, centroids):
        pca = PCA(n_components=2)
        data_2d = pca.fit_transform(data)
        centroids_2d = pca.fit_transform(centroids)
        sns.scatterplot(x=data_2d[:, 0], y=data_2d[:, 1], hue=labels, palette=sns.color_palette("bright")[:self.k])
        sns.scatterplot(x=centroids_2d[:, 0], y=centroids_2d[:, 1], color="black")
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1)
        plt.clf() 
    def fit(self):
        distance = pd.DataFrame(columns=[i for i in range(self.k)], index = [i for i in self.data.index])
        for _ in range(self.max_iter):
            self.__calculate_distance(distance)      
            labels = distance.idxmin(axis=1)
            self.__plot(self.data, labels, self.centroids)
            self.centroids = self.data.groupby(labels).mean()
            print(self.centroids)
        plt.show()       
       




model = KMeans()
data = pd.read_csv("Kmeans\data\players_22.csv")
model.load_data(data)
model.preprocess()
model.fit()
```